# Use test db for Django's built-in testing with SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, sqlalchemy

I have a project running in Django and connecting do SQLAlchemy ORM via sessionmaker, as showed below. It basicly handles http methods with a specified API (GET, POST, DELETE) and returns, posts, updates or deletes db entries.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker

self.session = sessionmaker(
            bind=create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pw@127.0.0.1/db')
```

Under `myproject.settings` I am using defaults like `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',`.

I would like to test whether the API is working as intended by simply interating through all possible methods and URIs which seem necessary to test. Testing is done with Django's `TestCase` class and its `Client` module. Works quite fine.

**My Problem**:
It is altering (especially deleting and updating columns within) the real db. Rather than using the "created and destroyed test_db" as Django's test output might indicate it is using the real db.

I kinda get why (I am bypassing Django's built-in db-connection with my SQLAlchemy connection), but I am interested in **how to fix this, i.e. using a true test_db.**

- Currently I am using a read-only mysql-user for testing, but that prevents me from testing actual POST and DELETE requests.
- I could try to use a different db for testing by mocking, but I would prefer another solution (I would have to create a dummy db from the real one, every time I ran a test)

PS: If you feel I have not provided enough code, give me a hint. But I feel people might get the idea of my problem and the solution is probably the mysql integration into Django, which I had not the need to do properly yet. Or more accuratly which I could not get working every time I tried.

EDIT: When trying to configure my database to

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pw',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    }
}
```

I get `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')` which I is due to not using pymysql here, I figure.